# Interpolating a variable inside a string in grails

Tags: grails, gsp, string-interpolation

Suppose I have a string saved into a domain property in the database in the format

```
 "This variable needs to be interpolated: ${variable}."
```

From the controller, I pass the value of this variable, for instance, `"FooBar"`.And then in GSP, page if I do sth. like

```
<%
    def testVar = ${MyDomainObj?.get(1)?.myProperty}
%>
variable is: ${variable}
variable is: ${testVar}
```

I get the outputs like:

```
variable is: FooBar
variable is: "This variable needs to be interpolated: ${variable}."
```

See the ${variable} that is returned directly from the database is not being interploated. What needs to be done so that I get the correct interpolated form of the expression ${variable} saved in the database instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Groovy Templates](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates).

You can leave the string in the domain the way you do now. To bind the variable to the string you need an instance of `groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine` and call `createTemplateEngine` and `make` on it.

```
import groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine
// ...
def engine = new SimpleTemplateEngine()
def binding = ["variable": variable]
def testVar = engine.createTemplate(MyDomainObj?.get(1)?.myProperty).make(binding)
```

Your output would then be as expected:

```
variable is: FooBar
variable is: "This variable needs to be interpolated: FooBar."
```

Answer (score 3):

1. in short: if the user has access to that database record, you'd better not. You'll allow the execution of an arbitrary code inside your application. Well, its execution context will be limited by a variable [Binding](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/Binding.html) that you provide, but that will be a domain object with a lot of methods anyway.
2. If you made sure it's secure, you need to interpret that string. [GStringTemplateEngine](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html) has a complete example.

Or maybe [Eval](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html) class will suit your needs - though it doesn't accept more than 3 parameters with a names x, y, z.